# Regex Unmatched parenthesis with double Square brackets

Tags: regex, regex-group

I looking for escape I tried many but didn't work this is a Regex for Discover Credit Card but I cant get it grouped so can check the Length of it

This is the regex

```
 ^[(6011|65|64[4-9]|622)(\d{1,4})]{16}$
```

Link: https://regex101.com/r/yEEpDt/1

Comment: What do you think `[` `]` is doing in a regex?

Comment: The outside one, groups the whole regex to match the {} given lenght

Comment: `[` `]` doesn't do grouping. Grouping is `(?:` `)`. And there is no "outer" bracket group; bracket groups don't nest.

Comment: So how do I group it together and check the whole length

Comment: Group what together? I have no idea what your regex is supposed to do because the code makes no sense and you didn't describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: Believe it or not, you aren't the first person to ever need to validate credit card numbers. https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to match 16 digits, no more, no less
and the number must start with one of your combinations,
this is the way to do it.

Use a lookahead assertion to verify the length,
then match as normal.

https://regex101.com/r/qo2cOL/1

`^(?=\d{16}$)(6011|65|64[4-9]|622)(\d{1,14})$`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 (?= \d{16} $ )
 (                             # (1 start)
      6011
   |  65
   |  64 [4-9] 
   |  622 
 )                             # (1 end)
 ( \d{1,14} )                  # (2) or even just a \d* will do here
 $
```

Comment: (?=\d{16)$) so this does the job?

Comment: @CharlieChandelier - It appears so. It just validates the line is 16 digits before matching continues.